# How can I construct a finite automaton for even decimal numbers?

Tags: numbers, decimal, finite-automata, automata

I have to do this exercise and am completely stumped as to how. I've constructed some FA's before, but using binary numbers. How can I do this but for even decimal numbers?

Comment: How would you express it as a regular expression?

Comment: (0-9)*(0|2|4|6|8) - I'm not very good with regex but that's what I think it should be (By the way I'm using formal notation for the regex).

Comment: Ok, so you should be able to draw a state diagram that corresponds to that regular expression.

Comment: My question then is, can I represent each edge in the FA diagram with more than one number (ex. edge from first state to second state is "1,3,5,7,9")?

Comment: Putting multiple labels on an edge is really just a shorthand for each label having its own edge; if you were to implement the FA, you'd have to break them out, but its much easier to read w/ multiple labels.

Answer (score 2):

It would be a simple one.

2 states: q1, q2.

- q1 is initial state.
- q2 is final state.
- if input digit on q1 is any even digit, make a move to q2.
- if input digit on q1 is any odd digit, remain on q1.
- if input digit on q2 is any even digit, remain on q2.
- if input digit on q2 is any odd digit, make a move back to q1.